# How does esLint detect which method 'should be placed after' another method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Often times, esLint would complain that a method should be placed after another method (I am using React so I'm not sure if it makes a difference). I am just wondering on what basis does it recommend a particular ordering?

All I know is that lifecycle methods should come first (in their proper order), then below them are the custom methods. But esLint would also complain about the ordering of those custom methods and I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`AirBnb react style guide`](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#ordering) which is what eslint rules follow, the ordering or method in React.Component shall be

> 1. optional static methods
> 2. constructor
> 3. getChildContext
> 4. componentWillMount
> 5. componentDidMount
> 6. componentWillReceiveProps
> 7. shouldComponentUpdate
> 8. componentWillUpdate
> 9. componentDidUpdate
> 10. componentWillUnmount
> 11. clickHandlers or eventHandlers like onClickSubmit() or onChangeDescription()
> 12. getter methods for render like getSelectReason() or getFooterContent()
> 13. optional render methods like renderNavigation() or renderProfilePicture()
> 14. render

Comment: How about other methods that do not fall under the list? (E.g. methods starting with 'sort' or 'filter' or 'handle' or 'anythingElse')

Comment: There is no particular order of the methods that you suggest except that they go in before render andd after lifecycle methods. You can check the relevant code here https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/lib/rules/sort-comp.js